# inner join Eloquent as JSON, bad answer

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with join in Eloquent. I have function:

```
public function getSearchQuery($search_phrase) {
    return Car::select("car_models.id", "car_models.name", "brands.name")
        ->join("car_models", "cars.car_model_id", "=", "car_models.id")
        ->join("brands", "car_models.brand_id", "=", "brands.id")
        ->get();
}
```

This function generate correct request SQL like:

```
select `car_models`.`name`, `brands`.`name` from `cars` inner join `car_models` on `cars`.`car_model_id` = `car_models`.`id` inner join `brands` on `car_models`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`id` where `cars`.`deleted_at` is null
```

and it works but I get only brand, without car_model, someone know why ? I return JSON to typeahead.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both columns you're selecting are called "name". Try using an alias:

```
Car::select("car_models.id", "car_models.name as model_name", "brands.name as brand_name")
```

and you should be fine.